# Relación muchos a muchos con atributo adicional

Tags: entity-framework

Buenas Buenas, una pregunta que no he podido solucionar, tengo una tabla, en entity framework, creada de la siguiente manera:

```html
 modelBuilder.Entity<Deportista>().HasMany<Clase>(c => c.Clases).WithMany(e => e.Alumnos).Map(e =>
               e.MapLeftKey("Alumno_idPersona"));

            modelBuilder.Entity<Deportista>().HasMany<Clase>(c => c.Clases).WithMany(
                e => e.Alumnos).Map(
                e => e.MapRightKey("Clase_idClase")

                );            
               modelBuilder.Entity<Alumno>().HasMany<Clase>(c => c.Clases).WithMany(e => e.Alumnos).Map(
                    e => e.ToTable("AlumnoClases")
                    );
```

Como ven, un alumno tiene varias clases, y una clase puede pertenecer a varios alumnos
eso me crea una tabla con el 
Clase_idClase   Alumno_idPersona
lo que quiero lograr es una tabla como esto
Clase_idClase   Alumno_idPersona  idUsuarioPersonaAlta
Osea agregar una columna donde guardar quien dio de alta esa relacion, o tambien la fecha, etc.
O está mal hecho? habria que generar una entidad Alumno_Clases que tenga las dos entidades?
Bueno espero se entienda la pregunta, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para poder agregar columnas extras a la relación debes crear la entidad que va a representar la relación.
Ejemplo:

**AlumnoClase**

```
public class Clase
{
   public int Id{ get; set; }
   public string Nombre{ get; set; }

   public List<AlumnoClase> AlumnosClases{ get; set; }
}

public class Alumno
{
   public int Id{ get; set; }
   public string Nombre{ get; set; }

   public List<AlumnoClase> AlumnosClases{ get; set; }
}

// Entidad Relación
public class AlumnoClase
{
   public int AlumnoId { get; set; }
   public int ClaseId { get; set; }

   public Alumno Alumno { get; set; }
   public Clase Clase{ get; set; }

   public string OtraColumna{ get; set; }
}

// FluentApi
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder){
    modelBuilder.Entity<AlumnoClase>().HasKey(k => new { k.AlumnoId, k.ClaseId});
    modelBuilder.Entity<AlumnoClase>().HasRequired(e => e.Alumno).WithMany(n => n.AlumnosClases).HasForeignKey(r => r.ClaseId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<AlumnoClase>().HasRequired(e => e.Clase).WithMany(n => n.AlumnosClases).HasForeignKey(r => r.AlumnoId);
}
```

Espero te sirva este ejemplo